# Mediawiki talk page links to normal page

Tags: mediawiki

I have a mediawiki installation which mostly works as expected otherwise. However, suddenly, one normal page's "talk" section links to another normal page instead of to the expected separate "talk" page.

This can be seen here: http://www.makehumancommunity.org/wiki/Documentation:Index

(As you can see, clicking "Discussion" you end up on "Faq:Index")

Anyone got an idea on what caused this and how I can fix it? My spontaneous idea would be to delete and recreate Faq:Index, but I'm worrying the error is a symptom of something larger being wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.makehumancommunity.org/w/api.php?action=query&meta=siteinfo&siprop=namespaces

By default, namespace 2N is a subject namespace and namespace 2N+1 is the talk namespace belonging to it.